# Unwanted browser scrollbar change when overlaying DIV is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a DIV with following style:

```
#dialog_overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2000;
    display:none;
}
```

At the bottom of my page there is a link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="test()">Test</a>
```

Function Test looks like this:

```
function test()
{
var overlay = $('#dialog_overlay')[0];

var body = document.body;
var html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight, body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight );

overlay.style.height = height + "px";
overlay.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

I would like to keep the browser scrollbar position unchanged as I click the link at the bottom of the page. What happens now is that when the DIV displayed, the scrollbar always pops up. Does anyone know how to keep the scrollbar at the position where it is before the link is clicked?

Comment: You could try giving it `position: fixed`.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` could be a possibility.

Comment: I have tried to change the position to fixed but it does not help. Overflow:hidden doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `event.preventDefault();`

```
function test(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After some further research I got working.